# VBA Get name of Dim, at index, in Array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

```
Sub foobar()

Dim wine As Variant
wine = Array("Red", "White", "Rose", "Sparkling")

Dim spirits As Variant
spirits = Array("Vodka", "Whiskey", "Rum", "Gin")

Dim beer As Variant
beer = Array("Ale", "Lager", "Pilsner", "Stout")

Dim inventory As Variant
inventory = Array(wine, spirits, beer)

Range("A1") = inventory(1)

End Sub
```

My current idea is to put the name of the array in the array,

```
wine = Array("wine", "Red", "White", "Rose", "Sparkling")

spirits = Array("spirits", "Vodka", "Whiskey", "Rum", "Gin")

beer = Array("beer", "Ale", "Lager", "Pilsner", "Stout")

inventory = Array(wine, spirits, beer)
```

Therefore inventory(x)(0) will always return the name of the array that way.

I want "A1" to show the name of the Dimension, i.e. spirits, but spirits itself is an array, so in "A1" I get the equivalent of inventory(1)(0).

Is there a better way to get the wine, spirits, or beer Dimensions returned as their name, than to include the name in the array (as above)?

Comment: They are variable and not objects.  You will need to store another array with the desired names as strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to reference things by name then a Dictionary is one solution.

```
Sub foobar()

    Dim wine As Variant
    wine = Array("Red", "White", "Rose", "Sparkling")

    Dim spirits As Variant
    spirits = Array("Vodka", "Whiskey", "Rum", "Gin")

    Dim beer As Variant
    beer = Array("Ale", "Lager", "Pilsner", "Stout")

    Dim inventory As Object, k
    Set inventory = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With inventory
        .Add "Wine", wine
        .Add "Spirits", spirits
        .Add "Beer", beer
    End With

    'access a specific item
    Debug.Print Join(inventory("Beer"), ",")

    'loop over items
    For each k in inventory.keys
        Debug.Print k, Join(inventory(k), ",")
    Next k

End Sub
```